# undefined method `round' for nil:NilClass when calculating difference between dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having my code crash at this point.  My model specs are working ok and are indeed calculating the difference between the dates.  However, my feature tests are crashing at this point (plus my app in the browser).

My callback method:

```
after_create :calculate
```

This is my spec failure report from the terminal:

```
5) Deleting rents Deleting rent for a given house
 Failure/Error: let!(:rent){FactoryGirl.create(:rent,amount:15000,house:runda,tenant:tenant,date:Date.today)}
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `round' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/rent.rb:96:in `interest_day'
 # ./app/models/rent.rb:41:in `interest_charge'
 # ./app/models/rent.rb:50:in `chargeable_balance'
 # ./app/models/rent.rb:54:in `current_status'
 # ./app/models/rent.rb:9:in `calculate'
 # ./spec/features/deleting_rents_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the method `interest_day`:

```
def interest_day
  return self.date - self.date.mday + tenant.organization.interest_date
end
```

Comment: Please, add `rent.rb` source code

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Something's `nil` I bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's not possible to help you with this directly as too much code is missing (and, frankly, it's probably to much to just cut&paste it in here and expect people to debug it in their brains...).

In cases like this, you have to figure out

1. Which variable is `nil`
2. Why is it `nil`

In your example, there will be some call `xyz.round` on line 96 of `rent.rb`. The `xyz` is nil (exactly what the message says). Find why that is and your problem will go away.

You can sprinkle your code with debug statements like `puts ">>>>> #{xyz.inspect}"` or `logger.debug "..."`, or find out how to single-step a debugger if you prefer that.